# Avoid matching the same value twice in string.matches() method in Java

Tags: java, overlapping-matches

Okay, I'm totally rewriting this question because this works and I want to know why it works.

Suppose I have a number, testNumber with a value of 567.

I want to know if the next two numbers (shouldPassTest and shouldFailTest) the same digits, but in different 10s places.

So here's the code:

```
int testNumber = 567;
int num1 = 5;
int num2 = 6;
int num3 = 7;

int shouldPassTest = 756; 
int shouldFailTest = 777;


if(Integer.toString(shouldPassTest).matches("[5,6,7][5,6,7][5,6,7]")
{
    //Do some cool stuff
}

if(Integer.toString(shouldFailTest).matches("[5,6,7][5,6,7][5,6,7]")
    {
        //Do some cool stuff
    }
```

What happens when you run that, is that each digit is tested from the range of available digits (5, 6, and 7). Theoretically, shouldFailTest ***should actually pass the test*** seeing as how 7 matches one of my three criteria, albeit 3 times.

But what happens is that 777 returns false, when tested. This is precisely the result I wanted in my code, but I want to know *why* it happened. Does the matches method test to make sure that each number is only matched once?

Thanks!

***This post was highly edited. After running my code, I found that the method does exactly what I want, but now I want to know why. Thanks.***

Comment: It sounds like you're looking to see if one number is an anagram of another.

Comment: "Different solution".  After using `Integer.toString`, break the strings down into characters, and use an array to hold the characters.  Then you can remove stuff from the array.  Even better would be to use a `Set`, but that won't work well if your numbers can have more than one of the same digit.  But don't try to solve this with regexes.

Comment: Yes, and weirdly, the code does exactly what I wanted. 777 returns false. Now I'm both pleasantly surprised and confused.

Comment: Actually, 777 doesn't return false.  You are checking to see if Integer.toString(shouldFailTest).matches("[5,6,7][5,6,7][5,6,7]") returns true in your above code.

Comment: The code you've excerpted won't even compile, because the parentheses aren't balanced in your `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following as regex is not a good solution to this problem:

```
public class Count {
    private int value;
    public Count() {
        value=0;
    }
    void increment() {
        value++;
    }
    void decrement() {
        value--;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
public static boolean isAnagram(int val1, int val2) {
    Map<Character, Count> characterCountMap=new HashMap<>();
    for(char c:Integer.toString(val1).toCharArray()) {
        Count count=characterCountMap.get(c);
        if(count==null) { count=new Count(); characterCountMap.put(c, count);}
        count.increment();
    }
    for(char c:Integer.toString(val2).toCharArray()) {
        Count count=characterCountMap.get(c);
        if(count==null) { return false; }
        else { count.decrement(); }
        if(count.getValue()==0) {
            characterCountMap.remove(c);
        }
    }
    return characterCountMap.size()==0;
}
```

Please run:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toString(shouldFailTest).matches("[5,6,7][5,6,7][5,6,7]"));
```

to view the actual return value.

Answer (score 0):

> Theoretically, shouldFailTest should actually pass the test seeing as
>   how 7 matches one of my three criteria, albeit 3 times.
>
> But what happens is that 777 returns false, when tested. This is
>   precisely the result I wanted in my code, but I want to know why it
>   happened. Does the matches method test to make sure that each number
>   is only matched once?

No, "777" does match the pattern you have specified "[5,6,7][5,6,7][5,6,7]"

Following condition in your code will evaluate to true.

`if(Integer.toString(shouldFailTest).matches("[5,6,7][5,6,7][5,6,7]"))`